# Does MSVC have something like __builtin_va_arg_pack?

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc

Does Visual C++ have something similar to [`__builtin_va_arg_pack`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html)?

> This built-in function represents all anonymous arguments of an inline
>   function. It can be used only in inline functions which will be always
>   inlined, never compiled as a separate function, such as those using
>   **attribute** ((**always_inline**)) or **attribute** ((**gnu_inline**)) extern inline functions. It must be only passed as
>   last argument to some other function with variable arguments. This is
>   useful for writing small wrapper inlines for variable argument
>   functions, when using preprocessor macros is undesirable. For example:
>
> ```
>       extern int myprintf (FILE *f, const char *format, ...);
>       extern inline __attribute__ ((__gnu_inline__)) int
>       myprintf (FILE *f, const char *format, ...)
>       {
>         int r = fprintf (f, "myprintf: ");
>         if (r < 0)
>           return r;
>         int s = fprintf (f, format, __builtin_va_arg_pack ());
>         if (s < 0)
>           return s;
>         return r + s;
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. But there's no need to use a gcc extension here, use vfprintf instead:

```
  int myprintf (FILE *f, const char *format, ...)
  {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    int r = fprintf (f, "myprintf: ");
    if (r < 0)
      return r;
    int s = vfprintf (f, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (s < 0)
      return s;
    return r + s;
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not what I asked for. I am aware of how to pass variadic arguments from a function taking a `va_list` to a `...` function, however I needed to pass arguments from one variadic function to another variadic function...

Comment: if you need this for something other than (v)printf, where only the variable arg function exists, but no alternative function taking a va_list , you are out of luck with the MSVC compiler.